# Javascript pass counter to function

Tags: javascript

I know how do closures work, but it is not very clear to me. 
How does the below snippet works under the hood (output's 0) :

```
function fillFunctionArr() {
    let arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = {
            inner: i,
            innerFunc: function() {
                console.log(this.inner)
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var ex = fillFunctionArr();
ex[0].innerFunc()
```

Sure, if it were declared as :

```
    arr[i] = {
        // inner: i,
        innerFunc: function() {
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
```

The output will be 10.
Why is the first snippet more preferable than the below one:

```
function fillFunctionArr() {
let arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = (function(qnt) {
        return function() {
            console.log(qnt)
        }
    })(i);
}
return arr;
}

var ex = fillFunctionArr();
ex[0]()
```

Comment: Who says it's more preferable? It works for exactly the same reasons that the last one works.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? What output did you expect?

Comment: You mean closure logic? I know, but first one keep reference inner to i counter, and its not clear for me - why it preserve i value and not just reference. For counterpart : function(i) { var inner = i; console.log(inner); }.   will print 10, coz of reference and not value. What is wrong in my understanding?

Comment: Is it due to object and function initialization difference (i mean object with parameters vs function object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'preferable' choice. The choice depends on logic of outer code, that you want to extend. Both initialized immediately on cycle iteration. It's just one of the edges of JS flexibility.